# как сделать добавление в вверх TableViewCell в Parse.com

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse.com

Кто нибудь из опытных подскажите как сделать чтоб при парсинге новой событие добавлялось вверх , а не вниз .Метод insertRow не срабатывает в Parse.com. Пробывал делать новый проект, простое добавление срабатывает.Прошу подскажите подробнее.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let sportCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sportCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell


                if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0  {



                 let soccer = soccerString[indexPath.row]

                sportCell.matchLabel.text = soccer.matchS
                soccerString[indexPath.row].imagePrS.getDataInBackground {(data, error) in
                sportCell.imageMatch.image = error == nil ? UIImage(data: data!) : nil
                    }
                }
                else if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

                let basket = basketString[indexPath.row]
                sportCell.matchLabel.text = basket.matchB
                basketString[indexPath.row].imagePrB.getDataInBackground {(data, error) in
                    sportCell.imageMatch.image = error == nil ? UIImage(data: data!) : nil

                }

                }  else if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
                sportCell.matchLabel.text = tennisString[indexPath.row].matchT

                tennisString[indexPath.row].imagePrT.getDataInBackground {(data, error) in
                        sportCell.imageMatch.image = error == nil ? UIImage(data: data!) : nil

                }

         }



            sportCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

            let date = Date()
            let calendar = Calendar.current



            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
            dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_UA")
            dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true


            if let today = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 0, to: date) {
                let todayString = dateFormatter.string(from: today)
                sportCell.dataSave.text = todayString

            } else if let yesterday = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: date) {
                let yesterdayString = dateFormatter.string(from:yesterday)
                sportCell.dataSave.text = yesterdayString
            } else {
                sportCell.dataSave.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

            }


                return sportCell
 }
```

вот код Parse :

```
func loadObjects1() {
        let query = Soccer.query() as! PFQuery<Soccer>


        query.findObjectsInBackground  { (objects, error) in
            if error == nil {



                self.soccerString = objects!

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }


            } else {
                print(error!)
            }

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Читай массив с конца в cellForRowAt

let revers = (soccerString.count - 1) - indexPath.row

Замени потом все indexPath.row на revers

Comment: Пожалуйста, старайтесь писать более развёрнутые ответы. Например в данном случае можно показать как именно в коде будет выглядеть чтение массива с конца.

Comment: let revers = (soccerString.count - 1) - indexPath.row

Comment: Замени потом все indexPath.row на revers.

Comment: Если это дополнения к ответу - добавьте их в сам ответ [через правку оного](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/744776/edit))

Comment: Ура помогло....Спасибо огромное всем!!!